# Having several projects on VS2010 and several "main" functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a game which has different "modules" that I am developping on separate projets for now, with VS2010.
So far I have each project in its own solution, and the main.cpp file is used  to basically initialize and do some quick tests on my project, that I change very often.
Is it possible (and how) to have 1 solution regrouping several projects while at the same time having also one "main" function per project that I could launch independently of the other projects to test one project specifically?

Comment: You're doing unamanged C++ right?  If you're doing Visual C++ .NET let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Put all your projects in one solution.  There is some button or menu option somewhere to Add a Project to a solution.  The advantage of this is that you can be editing multiple projects at once and Visual Studio will automatically rebuild everything that needs to be rebuilt when you compile.

All your reusable code (code used in more than on executable) should be divided up into projects that compile to DLLs.

For each executable you want to generate, you should have a project that compiles to an executable and references/links to the DLLs it depends on.  Each executable project will have its own `main` function which runs when you run the exe.

If you want to have a way to test your DLLs without generating an executable, you can make an entry point in your DLL and [run it using `rundll32`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787).  This would be good for developers testing your DLLs, but I would never tell a user to use `rundll32`.

Answer (score 0):

The build configurations are specific of each project, including which class contains the main method -IIRC, you can define several main in your project and define which one should be called through project configuration-.

Comment: Classes *never* contain main methods. I assume you're talking about setting the "Entry Point" property? This isn't recommended, you'll miss out on all of the work that the CRT does for you automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of C# which is the one I touched more recently. Didn't see the C++ tag of the question. Anyway you can have one main per project, not per solution